# Delayed sigmoidal function/logistic function

Tags: nonlinear-system, delay-differential-equations

I am really stuck in this problem, please help me out.

From my model i get following differential equation,

$\frac{df(t)}{dt} = 4 f(t) (1-X^{-1}-f(t))$

It is a sigmoidal equation and gives following solution,

$
f(t) = \frac{A}{1-e^{-k_{app} (t - t_{max})}} \\
$

Where,

$A = 1-X^{-1} \rightarrow$ equilibrium value i.e. saturation value.

$k_{app} = 4 (1-X^{-1}) \rightarrow$ Effective growth rate.

$t_{max} = \frac{1}{4 (1-X^{-1})} \ln\left( \frac{1-X^{-1}-f(0)}{f(0)}\right) \rightarrow$ time at which maximum growth rate occurs.

From this i calculation lag time i.e. time after which growth starts.

$t_{lag} = \frac{1}{4(1-X^{-1})} \ln \left( \frac{1-X^{-1}-f(0)}{f(0)}\right) - \frac{1}{2 (1-X^{-1})} $

But the property of lag time for my system is that for $X \rightarrow \infty$ my $\t_{lag}=0$ and hence i have to subtract $\frac{1}{4} \ln \left( \frac{1-f(0)}{f(0)} \right) -\frac{1}{2}$ from my lag time and then my model perfectly fits with the experimental data.

But now i have a problem that in order to accomodate my actual lag time in sigmoidal solution i have to renormalize my $t_{max}$ and $k_{app}$ as follows,

$t_{max} =  \frac{1}{4 (1-X^{-1})} \ln\left( \frac{1-X^{-1}-f(0)}{f(0)}\right) - \frac{1}{4} \ln \left( \frac{1-f(0)}{f(0)} \right)$

$k_{app} = 4 (X-1)$

After these adjustments to the final solution to logistic equation my entire model fits experimental data just fine.

But then I cant seem to figure out that what kind of differential equation will give me the solution that fits my model after renormalizing $t_{max}$ and $k_{app}$.

Kindly help me out with this. Its almost killing my more than a years work.

Thanks,

Nitin